# Using C++20 in 2019

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm starting a new C++ project that I probably will be working on and gradually extending for quite a while (at least a year). I'm trying to keep up with C++20 and I would love to start using some of the new features. I don't really care about supporting multiple compilers (GCC or Clang is enough). So far, I've been only experimenting with some of these features, but never considered using C++20 features in a real project.

Edit: My original question was about the current state of the C++20 standard and its support from compilers. I've been asked to narrow down the actual question, so I'll stick to my main reason to use C++20:

The main feature I'm interested in are the concepts. I've experimented with concepts on GCC with the `-fconcepts` flag. As I understand, this should correspond to the Concepts TS. But what's the state of concepts in the current standard? I've noticed that there are some minor syntactical differences between the TS and some other sources I've found on C++20. Is it realistic to use the current GCC's implementation (or maybe other compiler, that does it better) in a way that will be (at least with a high probability) valid in the actual finalized standard? Are there any reliable sources to keep track of the current agreed upon specification of concepts and other features?

The original questions:

**What's the state of C++20 standard?** When can I expect it to be complete, or at least in such a state that I can use it safely without worrying about my code not being valid in the final standard? I use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) as my primary source of information on language details. When it says `since C++20`, does that mean, that it is a finalized version that will stay in the standard?

**What's the state of C++20 support?** When can I expect it to be fully implemented (or at least the most important parts) in GCC, Clang, or maybe MSVC? In particular, what's the state of concepts and modules? I know that GCC has experimental support for concepts with `-fconcepts` (though [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) says, that it supports "TS only") and there's a branch of GCC that supports modules with `-fmodules` (but doesn't work with concepts).

Comment: More than likely full support for C++ 20 is going to be a year or two away.  One big change, ranges, needs a lot of machinery that is still being hammered out and the  the libraries need to be updated for it.

Comment: Your last question is too subject to opinion and to your situation. I have worked on projects where pushing the technology was valuable and writing for coming features was appropriate and on projects where stability was valuable and writing for old standards was appropriate.

Comment: For compiler support of features, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Are you "trying to keep up with C++20" just because of novelty or because you want to gain some benefits?

Comment: The committee schedule can be found at [P1000](https://wg21.link/p1000)

Comment: C++20 is a *draft* standard at this point, so compilers and associated libraries that support it are essentially experimental. If you use C++20 features, you run the risk that the implementation will be incomplete or inconsistent with the latest draft, that the draft standard may change, and that a feature you use and loved will work differently - or not at all - after an update of the (draft) standard and/or of your compiler and library. If you are willing to accept all that, go for it. But don't expect too much sympathy if some feature you rely on stops working sometime in the future.

Comment: @VTT Mostly because of concepts. They go well with my style of writing cpp code - lots of generic template stuff that requires use of sfinae and simmilar techniques to perform the compile time "type checks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++20 standard, baring catastrophic circumstances, will be complete in... 2020. This ain't rocket science ;)

The C++20 draft was designated feature complete at the last standards meeting, so new things will generally not be added. The likelihood of features being removed or having significant alterations is also low, but non-zero.

As for support for various C++20 features, that will take time. Not only that, it will take further time for said support to reach *maturity*. If you just want to play around with C++20 features, odds are good that you can do so in some compiler for many C++20 features sometime in 2020. But if you want to actually produce a product that's stable, it would be better to wait for compiler/library maturity until 2021 or 2022.

Visual Studio has a tendency to take longer to implement features than the other compilers. But generally, they take less time to implement *library* features, and will typically do so immediately upon shipping any dependent language features. By contrast, libc++ and libstdc++ tend to be much slower about getting library features done than their respective compilers about getting language features done.

Also for C++20, Microsoft has been pushing coroutines and modules *hard*, and they have the most mature implementations of both at present. So if that's what you're looking for, VS will likely have you covered more than the others.

Comment: Wow, that's actually surprising. I never thought that MSVC would be ahead of others in implementing new standards.

Comment: @McSim: They aren't. They are ahead on *specific features*, but due to the nature of VS's compiler and its handling of templates, it will likely take much longer to implement things like concepts and probably some of the more complex `constexpr` bits.

Comment: Catastrophic circumstances, might be happening.

Comment: @MaxPaython: Well technically, it is "done", it's just not quite ISO-done yet, and it's uncertain exactly when that will be happening. Though odds are good it'll still be called C++20 even if its ISO designation is from 2021. On the plus side, this might cause C++23 to be delayed, which would give the individual people more of a chance to mature their proposals and implementations, so that we can get more stuff into it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Some features are still missing, and some are published I guess. For example I wanted to use <syncstream> for thread-safe output, but guess it is not supported yet. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support